# How can I change the location of a virtual machine hard drive location?

Tags: hyper-v, hyper-v-server-2012-r2, settings

I have created a `windows server 2012 r2` server to be used as a `domain controler`
but I left the hard drive on the `C:` drive, instead of saving it with all other `virtual machine` stuff on the `D:` drive.

How can I change that?

[image]

Comment: Failover to your secondary, shutdown the VM, move the disk file, adjust VM config, start the VM, promote to primary again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Stop the guest VM. Locate and copy or move the entire folder structure for that VM to the new location. Once the VM files are in the new location, go back to the properties screen you have in your screenshot, and change the path to reflect the new location. Start the VM.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a detailed article about VM moving: https://www.altaro.com/hyper-v/hyper-v-storage-migration/

Comment: Hi, please edit to include some details that can apply to the OP, link only answer tend to expire with time when the link get down, Thanks!